# Changing the data-content on a loop using Javascriipt

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code:

```
<div>
<a href="#sizes" title="Select a Size" data-href="#sizes" class="size_selected" data-content="10.0">
</div>
```

I am trying to change the data-content using javascript. But i want the code to loop until the data-Content changes.

Comment: You forgot to post javascript code. But anyway, use a callback for that sort of thing, generally speaking.

Comment: _"But i want the code to loop until the data-Content changes."_ What is purpose of loop? What is "the code"?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `data` attributes using [the `dataset` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset):

```
<a id="my-link" href="#sizes" title="Select a Size" data-href="#sizes" class="size_selected" data-content="10.0">
```

---

```
document.getElementById('my-link').dataset.content = "5.0";
```

Comment: Is `.getElementByClassName` a method of `document`?

Comment: @guest271314 No, it's not. Thanks! :-)